# How can I disable all desktop notifications?

Tags: google-chrome

A while ago, the Hangouts desktop app started to display desktop notifications which no longer close on their own.

I've had it with Chrome desktop notifications and want to disable them completely.

I already disabled all notifications in the **Content settings** menu, even though there are some Google sites hardcoded as exceptions.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?  How you go about doing this, will depend if the application is generating the notifications windows itself, or if Windows is displaying the notifications (i.e. Windows 10).

Comment: @Ramhound I'm on Windows 10. It's not a Windows notification, it's an application-specific notification that has a completely different appearance than the Windows ones.